# check toggle and check default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Anybody have a better way to write this jquery method. If a user comes to the page and the checkbox is checked, show else hide, but if the user clicks the checkbox then display.

```
$('#rush').is(':checked') ? $("#rushJustificationContainer").show() : $("#rushJustificationContainer").hide();

$('#rush').click(function() {
    $("#rushJustificationContainer").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: it is acceptable, but i prefer to use short variables, so i don't find elements with long ids in many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
document.ready(function(){
    myToggle($('#rush').is(':checked'));
}

$('#rush').click(function(){
    myToggle(this.checked);
}

function myToggle(isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        $("#rushJustificationContainer").show();
    } else {
        $("#rushJustificationContainer").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function Toggle(o, toggle){
 o.toggle(toggle);
}

document.ready(function(){
  Toggle($("#rushJustificationContainer", $('#rush').checked); 
});

$('#rush').click(function(){
 Toggle($("#rushJustificationContainer", this.checked); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(function(){

      $("#rushJustificationContainer").css({display:$('#rush').is(':checked')?"block":"none"}); 

      $('#rush').click(function() {
          $("#rushJustificationContainer").toggle();
      });


    });
```

Comment: I agree, but just setting the display property isn't.

Comment: show() and hide() is enough to handle display logic. we do not bother how is it done!

Answer (score 0):

The question code is pretty optimal for a one-off; I'd prefer it over the alternatives so far.

You *might* shave some microseconds with:

```
$('#rush')[0].checked ? $("#rushJustificationContainer").show() : $("#rushJustificationContainer").hide();
```

While:

```
$("#rushJustificationContainer").toggle ( $('#rush').is (':checked') );
```

might be easier on the scrollbar. :)

~~~

The only other thing is if you might do this kind of thing more than once, then DRY-ize it.:

```
function activateCB_toDivControl (cbID, nodeID) {
    $('#' + nodeID).toggle ( document.getElementById (cbID).checked );

    $('#' + cbID).click (function (e) {
        $('#' + nodeID).toggle (e.currentTarget.checked);
    } );
}
```

Call like so:

```
activateCB_toDivControl ('rush', 'rushJustificationContainer');
activateCB_toDivControl ('COD',  'likeHellContainer');
```